# How update an array of object based on a value from dropdown?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object with key value pair I want to change the key and value for a particular id based on the dropdown value.

```
header: [
    { key: 'conditionalFrom', value: 'Conditional From', id:'conditional'},
    { key: 'conditionalTo', value: 'Conditional To', id:'conditional'},
    { key: 'computationFrom', value: 'Computation From'},
    { key: 'computationTo', value: 'Computation To'},
    { key: 'absOrPer', value: '% Absolute'},
    { key: 'value', value: 'Value'},
    { key: 'minAmt', value: 'Min Amount'},
    { key: 'maxAmt', value: 'Max Amount'},
],

if drodown value = "product"

expected output
header: [
    { key: 'productFrom', value: 'Product From'},
    { key: 'productTo', value: 'Product To'},
    { key: 'computationFrom', value: 'Computation From'},
    { key: 'computationTo', value: 'Computation To'},
    { key: 'absOrPer', value: '% Absolute'},
    { key: 'value', value: 'Value'},
    { key: 'minAmt', value: 'Min Amount'},
    { key: 'maxAmt', value: 'Max Amount'},
],

if drodown value = "base"
header: [
    { key: 'baseFrom', value: 'Base From'},
    { key: 'baseTo', value: 'Base To'},
    { key: 'computationFrom', value: 'Computation From'},
    { key: 'computationTo', value: 'Computation To'},
    { key: 'absOrPer', value: '% Absolute'},
    { key: 'value', value: 'Value'},
    { key: 'minAmt', value: 'Min Amount'},
    { key: 'maxAmt', value: 'Max Amount'},
],


const head = header.filter(el => {
if(el.id === 'conditional'){
  el.key = dropdown + "From"
  el.value = dropdown + "From"
}
})
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be valid javascript.

Answer (score -1):

Just use `map` to create a new set of objects looking for what you want to replace.

```js
const input = {header: [
    { key: 'conditionalFrom', value: 'Conditional From', id:'conditional'},
    { key: 'conditionalTo', value: 'Conditional To', id:'conditional'},
    { key: 'computationFrom', value: 'Computation From'},
    { key: 'computationTo', value: 'Computation To'},
    { key: 'absOrPer', value: '% Absolute'},
    { key: 'value', value: 'Value'},
    { key: 'minAmt', value: 'Min Amount'},
    { key: 'maxAmt', value: 'Max Amount'},
]};

const replace="product";

const result = {
    header: input.header.map( ({key,value}) => ({ key: key.replace("conditional",replace), value}))
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You should replace the value too and make it case insensitive and only modify the objects if their id's are 'computational'